# Want to remove everything after nth "/" from hyperlink in Notepad++ or Excel

Tags: excel, replace, notepad++

I need some help: looking for a way to remove everything after the nth occurrence (most likely 4th or 5th) of "/" in a hyperlink. For instance, if I have

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=https://forbes.com/&refURL=&referrer=
```

my desired output is:

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Additionally, if a link only has <4 "/", I'd like to keep everything. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In general, this is easy to do in Excel (if you know excel functions), but please show us what you have tried and what is not working. Your question shows no research effort on your part, and SO is not a "hey, do this for me" site. It's programmers helping programmers with their *programming* problems.

Answer (score 2):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((?:[^/]*/){5}).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of lin
  (             : start group 1
    (?:         : start non capture group
      [^/]*     : 0 or more any character that is not a slash
      /         : a slash
    ){5}        : group must appear 5 times
  )             : end group 1
  .*            : 0 or more any character
$               : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (ie. everything before the 5th slash)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple formula, although I agree with @Scott Holtzman that you should show some effort before posting question here. In Excel enter this formula in cell `B1` if your links are in cell `A1`.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~~~~",5),FIND("~~~~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","~~~~",5),1)-1)&"/",A1)
```

[image]